# Lost atoms in LAMMPS

Tags: lammps

What I am trying to simulate is an evaporation of ammonia water, after being heated by a gold plate underneath. But I have received a lost atom error during minimization. If I removed the minimization command along with the velocity command, it gives bond atom missing error.

I am assuming that it is due to the water penetrating the gold plate but I have tried out all the fix/wall commands and fix/addforce command, the results are still the same.

Below are my input script:

```
# Create a simulation box
units real
dimension 3
atom_style      full
bond_style      hybrid morse harmonic
angle_style     harmonic
dihedral_style  charmm
improper_style  umbrella
special_bonds   dreiding
pair_style      hybrid/overlay lj/cut/coul/long 12.0 hbond/dreiding/lj 4 6 6.5 90 
kspace_style    pppm 1.0e-4
kspace_modify   slab 3.0
dielectric      1.0
boundary p p f

region awmix block 0 40.07 0 40.07 -5 100.07  #ammonia water region
create_box 4 awmix bond/types 2 angle/types 2 extra/bond/per/atom 3 extra/angle/per/atom 3 extra/dihedral/per/atom 3 extra/improper/per/atom 3 extra/special/per/atom 3
read_data ATLASparticle.data add append

region plate block 0 40.07 0 40.07 -5 -1 # gold plate
lattice fcc 4.08
create_atoms 4 region plate
lattice none 1.0

group liquid type 2 3 
group solid type 4

# Define interaction potential
pair_coeff 1 1 lj/cut/coul/long 0.0 0.0
pair_coeff 1 2 lj/cut/coul/long 0.00278209 3.0544905
pair_coeff 1 3 lj/cut/coul/long 0.00309354 2.939787
pair_coeff 2 2 lj/cut/coul/long 0.21 3.36 
pair_coeff 2 2 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 i 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 2 2 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 j 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 2 3 lj/cut/coul/long 0.08606498 3.1478565
pair_coeff 2 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 i 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 2 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 j 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 3 3 lj/cut/coul/long 0.1553 3.166
pair_coeff 3 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 i 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 3 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 j 4.0 2.75 4
bond_coeff 1 morse 101.905 2.3470 1.0124
bond_coeff 2 harmonic 600.0 1.0
angle_coeff 1 103.045 106.67
angle_coeff 2 75.0 109.47

mass 4 196.96657 # gold

pair_coeff 4 4 lj/cut/coul/long 11.697 2.574

pair_coeff 1 4 lj/cut/coul/long 0.0 0.0
pair_coeff 2 4 lj/cut/coul/long 0.0 0.0
pair_coeff 3 4 lj/cut/coul/long 2.8675 0.0554
pair_coeff 3 4 lj/cut/coul/long 2.8675 0.0114

# Count molecule
variable oxygen atom "type==3"
variable nitrogen atom "type==2"
group oxygen dynamic all var oxygen
group nitrogen dynamic all var nitrogen
variable nO equal count(oxygen)
variable nN equal count(nitrogen)
fix oxy all ave/time 1000 1 1000 v_nO file number_oxygen.dat
fix nit all ave/time 1000 1 1000 v_nN file number_nitrogen.dat

# Count energy
variable kinetic_energy equal ke
variable potential_energy equal pe
variable pressure equal press
variable temperature equal temp
variable volume equal vol
fix myat1 all ave/time 1000 1 1000 v_kinetic_energy v_potential_energy v_pressure v_temperature v_volume file energy.dat

#Provide initial velocity to the atoms by setting temperature of our system = 298.15K
velocity all create 298.15 102939 dist gaussian mom yes rot yes

#Perform minimization
minimize 2.0e-5 0.001 10000 10000
timestep 1
reset_timestep 0

#Setting system
neigh_modify    every 1 delay 0 check yes

# Results
dump dump03 all custom 1000 dump03.lammpstrj id type x y z ix iy iz vx vy vz
thermo_style custom step time temp pe ke etotal press vol
thermo 1000

# run
fix wall solid addforce 1.0 0.0 0.0 region plate
fix 2 all nve/limit 1
fix 3 all temp/berendsen 80 80 1
timestep 0.1
run 50000
```

I'm not sure if it is related to the data file (ATLASparticle.data = ammonia water data file) but I don't think that's the case because I have run similar simulation (same data file and parameters) and there is no overlapping.

```
#Create a simulation box
units real
dimension 3
atom_style      full
bond_style      hybrid morse harmonic
angle_style     harmonic
dihedral_style  charmm
improper_style  umbrella
special_bonds   dreiding
pair_style      hybrid/overlay lj/cut/coul/long 12.0 hbond/dreiding/lj 4 6 6.5 90 
kspace_style    pppm 1.0e-4
dielectric      1.0
boundary p p p

region awmix block -50 58.63 -50 58.63 -50 58.63  #ammonia water region
create_box 3 awmix bond/types 2 angle/types 2 extra/bond/per/atom 3 extra/angle/per/atom 3 extra/dihedral/per/atom 3 extra/improper/per/atom 3 extra/special/per/atom 3
read_data ATLASparticle.data add append

group vapor type 2 3

#Define interaction potential
pair_coeff 1 1 lj/cut/coul/long 0.0 0.0
pair_coeff 1 2 lj/cut/coul/long 0.00278209 3.0544905
pair_coeff 1 3 lj/cut/coul/long 0.00309354 2.939787
pair_coeff 2 2 lj/cut/coul/long 0.21 3.36 
pair_coeff 2 2 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 i 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 2 2 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 j 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 2 3 lj/cut/coul/long 0.08606498 3.1478565
pair_coeff 2 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 i 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 2 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 j 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 3 3 lj/cut/coul/long 0.1553 3.166
pair_coeff 3 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 i 4.0 2.75 4
pair_coeff 3 3 hbond/dreiding/lj 2 j 4.0 2.75 4
bond_coeff 1 morse 101.905 2.3470 1.0124
bond_coeff 2 harmonic 600.0 1.0
angle_coeff 1 103.045 106.67
angle_coeff 2 75.0 109.47

#Provide initial velocity to the atoms by setting temperature of our system = 298.15K
velocity all create 298.15 102939 dist gaussian mom yes rot yes

#Perform minimization
minimize 2.0e-5 0.001 10000 10000
timestep 1
reset_timestep 0

#Setting system
neigh_modify    delay 10 every 1 check yes

variable oxygen atom "type==3"
variable nitrogen atom "type==2"
group oxygen dynamic all var oxygen
group nitrogen dynamic all var nitrogen
variable nO equal count(oxygen)
variable nN equal count(nitrogen)
fix oxy all ave/time 1000 1 1000 v_nO file number_oxygen_test.dat
fix nit all ave/time 1000 1 1000 v_nN file number_nitrogen_test.dat

dump dumpMIX all custom 1000 dumpMIXtest.lammpstrj id type x y z ix iy iz vx vy vz
thermo_style custom step time temp pe ke etotal press vol
thermo 1000

variable kinetic_energy equal ke
variable potential_energy equal pe
variable pressure equal press
variable temperature equal temp
variable volume equal vol
fix myat1 all ave/time 1000 1 1000 v_kinetic_energy v_potential_energy v_pressure v_temperature v_volume file energy_test.dat

#run
fix         2 all nve
fix         3 all temp/berendsen 413.15 413.15 100.0
fix         4 all temp/rescale 1 413.15 413.15 0.05 1.0
fix         5 all press/berendsen iso 4.0 4.0 1000.0
timestep 0.1
run 1000000
```

*You can get the data file from link below:
https://github.com/JackyXes/ATLASparticle/blob/main/ATLASparticle.data
Please ignore the coordinate values because I changed them for 2 different scripts.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit

[image]

As you can see, there are molecules entering the bottom plate. I tried using fix wall/region on the plate region but I got a illegal command error instead.

Comment: Jack, the link you have posted for the data file doesn't work, maybe because it's a private repository? Please add the data file with your question, so that I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Also, an observation from the codes, in the 1st case you have used fixed boundary conditions in the z-direction. If an atom moves outside the box from +/- z direction it will be deleted on the next timestep (unlike in periodic boundary conditions where it is reintroduced again from the other direction). This will typically generate an error unless you have set the `thermo_modify lost` option to allow for lost atoms.

Comment: Hi @Magic_Number, first of all thanks for your replies, I have updated the visibility of the repository so please have a look. The file is quite big (in amount of words) so I don't think it is possible to post it in the question. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Besides that, actually the fixed z-boundary is based on several papers. The first script only ends with minimization / relaxation. After this is done I will run another timestep with fix evaporate to delete any molecules that enter the zhi region.

Comment: HI @Magic_Number, after running with more recorded timestep, I think the main reason is because the molecule pass through zlo and have atom deleted, as result, the bond connecting that atom is lost. But I know having a fixed z boundary is possible to run because that's what I found from several lammps papers. Just that I am missing a command to prevent the molecules from passing through the zlo boundary. Once again, thanks.

Comment: Hi Jack, exactly. That is why you have lost atoms error. Try `fix wall/reflect` command maybe?

Comment: Hi @Magic_Number, when I use fix wall/reflect, the gold plate got pushed up from the bottom. Do you know why this happens? My command is
fix 1 all wall/reflect zlo -1 units box

Comment: try `EDGE` in place of `-1 units box`, if the problem persists, that means you need to modify your zlo boundary such a way that the gold plate atoms are not overlapping the edge of the boundary.

Comment: Also I found out that it might not because of the zlo issue, because after running again with fix wall/reflect, (since the gold plate got pushed up, I can see the bottom region clearly) there are no molecules passing through zlo boundary.

If you look at my screenshot, you can see an atom (Hydrogen) appears on the top. I think it might because of molecules entering the gold plate and has its bond broken. 

Sorry for keep changing my thoughts on this issue. I'm quite new to lammps so I don't know which answer is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140290/discussion-between-magic-number-and-jack).

Comment: @Magic_Number next time please use the [LAMMPS chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps) instead of creating a new one. Please support [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772) if you feel that this process should be simpler.

Answer (score 6):

You have made many changes between the second attached input (which is a bulk ammonia-water mixture at 413K -- albeit with a very strange choice of two thermostats) and the first input. The first input has an ammonia-water mixture:

- with one non-periodic axis
- in an extremely inhomogeneous box (there's vacuum!)
- and a slab of gold
- all thermostatted together
- at 80K

Any of those changes, or combination of those changes could have broken your simulation (and remember -- just because your first simulation ran does not even guarantee that *it* is correct). You have to test them one by one and proceed via elimination.

(Note that "my input crashed" questions are usually not easily answered on StackExchange because the diagnostic process invariably involves some back-and-forth. The process is more suited to a forum, such as the LAMMPS forum at MatSci.org.)

Comment: Actually I posted the second script is just to show that the data file is not the one causing this issue. What I trying to do is to simply prevent the molecules from passing through the gold plate.

Comment: Saying what _does not_ cause the issue is of limited help in working out what _does_ cause the issue. You have one "working" input which, after a few changes, yields one "non-working" input -- I simply observe that almost certainly one of those changes was the one that made your input not work, and finding that one change is what you might want to do.

Comment: And if what you are trying to do is to "simply prevent the molecules from passing through the gold plate", then how do you know if you're still making _a useful model of a physical system_, not just filling a hard drive with numbers? After all, you could charge all your particles negative and let them repel each other, or accelerate all your molecules upwards at 2 _g_, or fill a plexiglass box with ball bearings. (I'm not being rude. This is an actual experiment we ran as second year undergrads to observe the barometric distribution.)

Comment: What I'm saying is that your main issue is that _your gold-fluid system is no longer physically relevant_, and you need to design a physically relevant MD simulation of a gold-fluid interface. That your simulation shows water seeping through gold is a _symptom_. "Fixing" that seepage will not necessarily fix your simulation, any more than giving a patient aspirin will cure her brain tumour (even if her brain tumour is what is giving her headaches).

Comment: I see, so what you are saying is using fix wall is not the correct method but I should use correct pair_coeff to ensure that the molecules will not pass through the plate?

Comment: TBH after running with different settings, I found out from my second script, the issue might because of the Hydrogen bonds broken from (Oxygen/Nitrogen). After minimization (in second script) I found 4 free hydrogen bonds. Since in the first script I don't have fix evaporate, the free hydrogen that passes through zhi is lost. Guess I need to amend the first script so there will be no free hydrogen atoms.

Comment: If you comment too much the system will try to move you to chat. If that happens please don't click the button. We don't want more chat rooms right now. Please use an existing one.

Comment: Stack Exchange tends to handle these kinds of questions by back-and-forth in the comments and then posting the eventual solution as an answer.

Comment: user253751 has done 0 activity on this site until that comment, so I wouldn't recommend to base your thoughts on how the site works based on their comment. Well there was 1 comment in 2020.

Comment: @ShernRenTee, Actually I have this question in my mind for a long time and I'm glad you pointed that out. The box is a vacuum space. Is there a way to make it non-vacuum (like ambient)? By changing the pressure (using npt or box/relax), will this work?

Thanks

Comment: @Jack it depends on what you are simulating, what properties you need to calculate, etc etc etc. This comes back to the previous comment by Shren, do you have "a useful model of a physical system"? Your model should determine whether you need a vacuum, or in ideal gas, whether the system you want to simulate is finite or homogeneous, etc.